# CSS Sibling Selector

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Here are html codes:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="menu-wrap">
    <ul>
     <li>
       <input type="radio" id="link1" />
     </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="content-wrap">
    <div id="link1-content"><p>Just a paragraph</p></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here are css codes:

```css
#link1:checked ~ #link1-content { display: none;}
```

I am trying to create css click with input[type=radio]. My problem is that the sibling selector does not work.

How can I write appropriate sibling selector?

Comment: You should use JavaScript here.

Comment: I know how to do that with JS, but I need css only.

Comment: "My problem is that the sibling selector does not work". That's because those elements aren't siblings.

Comment: Good point, is there any hack in css?

Comment: Nope, not until what you might call CSS4. JavaScript is the only way to do it now.

Comment: @j08691: Not even with CSS4... in its current state anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to do something sibling selectors cannot do.  You will not be able to style `#link1-content` because it does not share the same parent as `#link1:checked`. 
As @sirko said, this is something that should be accomplished with Javascript/JQuery (see my snippet below).

**Source**
[Child and Sibling selectors -- CSS Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/child-and-sibling-selectors/)

> Note that in both the general sibling and adjacent sibling selectors the logic takes place within the same parent element.

**A very simple jQuery solution:**

```
$('#link1').change(function(){
  $('#link1-content').toggle();
});
```

[Codepen example](http://codepen.io/NickTomlin/pen/jwluh)

Comment: Thanks, I know How to do that with jQuery, I wanted a hack in pure css.