# How to select all siblings child together

Tags: jquery, jquery-traversing

I want that if i hover on a div then add abc class in rest div

```css
.abc{
  color:Red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
 <h2>h2</h2>
 <p>p</p>
</div>
<div>
 <h2>h2</h2>
 <p>p</p>
</div>
<div>
 <h2>h2</h2>
 <p>p</p>
</div>
```

I want to use jquery traversing for this code

Comment: Hi, I do not fully understand your question, if you hover on one div then the rest of the divs should be given the class "abc", but the div you are hovering on should have nothing?

Comment: yes that's  exactly what i want

Comment: and on mouseout the class must be remove

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS Sibling Selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14367641/css-sibling-selector)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this will help you.

```js
$("div").hover(function() {
    $(this).siblings("div").addClass("abc");
}, function() {
    $(this).siblings("div").removeClass("abc");
});
```

```css
.abc{
  color:Red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
 <h2>h2</h2>
 <p>p</p>
</div>
<div>
 <h2>h2</h2>
 <p>p</p>
</div>
<div>
 <h2>h2</h2>
 <p>p</p>
</div>
```